# What is the name of this song from Sekaiichi Hatsukoi?

Tags: music, sekai-ichi-hatsukoi

I recently was looking at the Sekaiichi Hatsukoi OST and I came across this one I really liked. Video is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8McEf9YMtM) from YouTube.

Just for reference it plays during Season 1, Episode 12 of Sekaiichi Hatsukoi and I was able to find the scene [here](http://youtu.be/ry-Tuz-wZSM?t=3m11s).

Does anyone know the name of the song playing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely looking for 恋は切なく (Koi Wa Setsunaku, Love is Painful), track 15 of OST 1:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NL-HCA67v0

Comment: You found it. Just wondering, but how did you find it? Did it pop up in suggestions on YouTube?